# Выбрать текст в кавычках и поместить в span

Tags: javascript

```
<h5>Пластиковое окно "Эконом"</h5>
```

Требуется то что в кавычках выделить в span.
Знаю что можно с помощью регулярных выражений

Нужно чтобы стало так

```
<h5>Пластиковое окно "<span>Эконом</span>"</h5>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var h5 = document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0],
str = h5.innerHTML,
p1 = str.indexOf('"'),
part1 = str.slice(0, p1),
world = str.slice(p1+1, str.lastIndexOf('"'));

h5.innerHTML = part1 + '"<span>' + world + '</span>"';
```

```html
<h5>Пластиковое окно "Эконом"</h5>
```

И более короткое решение:

```js
var h5 = document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
h5.innerHTML = h5.innerHTML.replace(/(.+)"(.+)"/, '$1"<span>$2</span>"');
console.log(h5.innerHTML);
```

```html
<h5>Пластиковое окно "Эконом"</h5>
```

Comment: @lendik, добавил ещё и более короткое решение.

Answer (score 1):

text.replace( /Эконом/g, "Эконом" ) )

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы текст был любой в ковычках

Comment: Используя регулярку вида /".+"/ ищите текст в кавычках. После это же выражение используете в реплейсе, но там заменяете на найденную строку в прошлом шаге с помощью переменной. ПС возможно можно сделать без использования предварительного поиска